# How can I use command line telnet client to open a raw connection - like PuTTY?

Tags: telnet

I need to use telnet to talk with a socket server which is not a standard Telnet server.
I do not want any Telnet negotioation or interference of any kind in the data.

This is available as 'raw mode' in PuTTy and I need the same functionality in Linux.

Comment: [Do you know `netcat`?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Opening_a_raw_connection_to_port_25_.28like_telnet.29)

Comment: I added that I need a **command line** telnet client (so Putty on Linux does not work for me).

Comment: I am connecting to a MOXA product which is a TCP server for remotely connecting to a serial port (of a legacy product). It needs to be _raw_ so that all keystrokes will be sent as is.

Comment: Basically I need 'telnet-like' functionality but without the protocol. I also tried __netcat__ (suggested above) but that did not work nicely - it is in line edit mode and keystrokes like ^C are not passed.

Comment: As another pointer, have a look at [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/), it is a lot more feature-packed than `netcat`; maybe you can utilize it.

Comment: Putty's "RAW" mode is not really RAW. When you press Ender, it will send CR/LF. I don't know any other way to type CR other than Enter.

Answer (score 13):

Use netcat, it provides command line raw sockets, a very handy utility, I often use it to move data between servers when encryption is not required, for example:

Server1

```
# nc -l -p 1234 | zcat | mysql -u root databaseName
```

Server2

```
# mysqldump -u root databaseName | gzip | nc Server1 1234
```

Comment: This is an awesome tip!  However, when I tried it between two terminal windows on MacOS the first line errored.  My man page for nc says it is an error to use -p with -l.  It worked like a champ when I omitted the -p

Answer (score 5):

At risk of sounding daft, why not just use PuTTY? If you already like the functionality it gives you, just run it. PuTTY is available for [Linux or Windows](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

As already pointed out in comments, telnet isn't raw - it expects certain protocols to be followed.

Comment: +1 Rory. Telnet isn't raw. Use 'set options' on the `telnet> ` prompt and you'll see the protocols in action.

Comment: Putty "RAW" mode is not really RAW. When you press Enter it sends CR/LF.

Answer (score 2):

You can use telnet to connect to any port provided that there is something listening to that port and it is not blocked by a firewall.

```
telnet alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 25
telnet google.com 80
```

Will all work fine. However, you must know what protocol is used by the other end of the connection otherwise, it is kind of pointless.

Note that telnet sends packets unencrypted.

Comment: Beware: telnet seems "raw", but it isn't. There is already some protocol level involved even if limited. What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: @Ouki, the TELNET *protocol* is quite complex, sure. The telnet *'program* will usually revert to a raw operation mode if not connecting to a TELNET server.

Answer (score 0):

Very old, but I found this to work for a MOXA unit:

```
stty raw && nc <ip> 23 && stty sane
```

Answer (score 0):

Still relevant after all these years.

This works fine in the `~/.bash_aliases`, opening up a `moxa` shell in a tab without the local echo: (parameter is moxa port number)

```
function moxat(){
  mate-terminal --tab --title="moxa1 $1" -e "bash -c 'stty raw -echo && \ 
  nc <ip> $1 && stty sane'" 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this exact line:

```
sudo socat tcp-l:2023,reuseaddr,fork exec:/bin/login,pty,setsid,setpgid,stderr,ctty
```

That will let you connect with a raw socket from the Moxa and get a command line prompt on the host machine. From there you can Telnet or SSH at will to any system with ease.